# xpath result list with empty elements

Tags: web-scraping, xpath

I have this html structure that I want to scrap with xpath, and I'm getting some empty elements in the resulting list:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="content title">File 1</div>
  <div class="content version"><span>Version: </span>1.1</div>
  <div class="content date"><span>Date: </span>01-01-2022</div>
  <div class="content size"><span>Size: </span>20Mb</div>
</div>
```

The ideal expected result is: `['File 1', '1.1', '01-01-2022', '20Mb']`

other acceptable results would be:
`['File 1', 'Version: 1.1', 'Date: 01-01-2022', 'Size: 20Mb']`
or
`['File 1', 'Version:', '1.1', 'Date:', '01-01-2022', 'Size:', '20Mb']` > *this is the one I was trying in my example below*

Instead I'm getting: **`['File 1', '', 'Version:', '1.1', '', 'Date:', '01-01-2022', '', 'Size:', '20Mb', '']`** using the xpath sentence:
**`//div[@class="row"]/descendant::*/text())`**

*(tried different xpath but can't get rid of those empy elements in between)*

**Note:** note that the title section doesn't have a span tag as the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it!

`//div[@class="row"]/div/text()[last()]`